# K-NN: training MSE with K=1 not equal to 0

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, knn, supervised-learning

In theory, the training MSE for k = 1 should be zero. However, the following script shows otherwise. I first generate some toy data: x represents sleeping hours and y represents happiness. Then I train the data and predict the outcome. Finally, I calculate the MSE for the training data via two methods. Can anyone tell me what goes wrong?

```py
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor

model = KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=1)

import numpy as np
x = np.array([7,8,6,7,5.7,6.8,8.6,6.5,7.8,5.7,9.8,7.7,8.8,6.2,7.1,5.7]).reshape(16,1)
y = np.array([5,7,4,5,6,9,7,6.8,8,7.6,9.3,8.2,7,6.2,3.8,6]).reshape(16,1)

model = model.fit(x,y)

for hours_slept in range(1,11):
    happiness = model.predict([[hours_slept]])
    print("if you sleep %.0f hours, you will be %.1f happy!" %(hours_slept, happiness))


# calculate MSE

# fast method
def model_mse(model,x,y):
    predictions = model.predict(x)
    return np.mean(np.power(y-predictions,2))
print(model_mse(model,x,y))
```

The output:

```
if you sleep 1 hours, you will be 6.0 happy!
if you sleep 2 hours, you will be 6.0 happy!
if you sleep 3 hours, you will be 6.0 happy!
if you sleep 4 hours, you will be 6.0 happy!
if you sleep 5 hours, you will be 6.0 happy!
if you sleep 6 hours, you will be 4.0 happy!
if you sleep 7 hours, you will be 5.0 happy!
if you sleep 8 hours, you will be 7.0 happy!
if you sleep 9 hours, you will be 7.0 happy!
if you sleep 10 hours, you will be 9.3 happy!
0.15999999999999992 #strictly larger than 0!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In theory, the training MSE for k = 1 should be zero

An implicit assumption here is that there are not *duplicate* samples `x`, or, to be precise, that same features `x` have same values `y`. Is it the case here? Let's see

```python
pred = model.predict(x)

np.where(pred!=y)[0]
# array([9])
```

So, there is a single value where `y` and `pred` are indeed different:

```python
y[9]
# array([7.6])

pred[9]
# array([6.])
```

where

```python
x[9]
# array([5.7])
```

How many samples `x` have a value of `5.7`, and what are the correspondent `y`'s?

```python
ind = np.where(x==5.7)[0]
ind
# array([ 4,  9, 15])

y[ind]
# result:
array([[6. ],
       [7.6],
       [6. ]])

pred[ind]
# result
array([[6.],
       [6.],
       [6.]])
```

So, what is actually happening here is that for `x=5.7` the algorithm unsuprisingly cannot decide unambiguously which exact sample is the single closest neighbor - the one with `y=6` or the one with `y=7.6`; and here it has chosen the one that does not coincide with the true `y`, leading to a non-zero MSE.

I guess that digging into the knn source code one would be able to justify exactly how such cases are handled internally, but I'm leaving this as an exercise.

Answer (score 3):

In your data, `x` has multiple labels for `5.7` in `y`, `6` and `7.6`. After training, the algorithm assigns label `6` for the variable `5.7`, and during evaluation, when it encounters `5.7` for the second time, it returns `6` but not `7.6`. So, the squared error of this pair is `(7.6 - 6)**2 = 2.56` and the mean squared error, considering other errors are `0`, is `1/16 * 2.56 = 0.16` - exactly your result.